# SQL query, update from, multiple inner join

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, subquery

lets say I have 3 tables in my SQL database:

***AspNetUserRoles*** - hold records that links user with role
***AspNetUsers*** - holds users
***AspNetRoles*** - holds roles

I wanted to update role assigned to user whose email is: some@email.com

I created this query and it works:

```
-- Update tester account role
Update  AspNetUserRoles
Set RoleId = 4
From AspNetUsers as b Inner Join AspNetUserRoles as a
    On a.UserId = b.Id Where b.Email = 'some@email.com'
```

Now, how to edit this query, instead of supplying ***RoleId*** (in this case 4), retrieve specific role ID from its table by specifying its name? ***AspNetRoles*** table has field 'name', I tried with another inner join but failed. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: MSSQL - I have updated tags, sorry my mistake.

Comment: How would you, logically, match the role it to the email?

Comment: I am using this query for automation testing, email is known for me (it is email from account set up for automation tester, thus it never change) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `UPDATE` query I've removed the `JOIN` because you have this information in your mail table.

So I've add the subquery to update your RoleId

Try this:

```
UPDATE AspNetUserRoles
SET RoleId = (SELECT c.id FROM AspNetRoles c WHERE c.name = 'MyRoleName')
FROM AspNetUsers as b 
WHERE b.Email = 'some@email.com'
AND AspNetUserRoles.UserId = b.Id
```

Comment: It works, I will accept answer within few minutes that remained, thank you.

Comment: @Matthewek: Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a query to fetch the id of the role depending of the name

```
SELECT r.id
FROM AspNetRoles r
WHERE r.name = 'YourRoleName'
LIMIT 1
```

And use this query as subquery in your main :

```
Update  AspNetUserRoles
Set RoleId = 
(
    SELECT r.id
    FROM AspNetRoles r
    WHERE r.name = 'YourRoleName'
    LIMIT 1
)
From AspNetUsers as b Inner Join AspNetUserRoles as a
    On a.UserId = b.Id Where b.Email = 'some@email.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `JOIN` like this:

```
update  aur
    set RoleId = 4
from AspNetUsers au join
     AspNetUserRoles  ur
     on aur.UserId = au.Id join
     AspNetRoles r
     on ur.RoleId = r.roleId
where au.Email = 'some@email.com' and
      r.Name = ?;
```

This seems strange, though.  `ApsNetUserRoles` sounds like a junction table.  I would expect you to add a role by inserting a role into this table.

Comment: Gordon : *"how to edit this query, instead of supplying RoleId (in this case 4), retrieve specific role ID from its table by specifying its name?"*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Update AspNetUserRoles
    Set AspNetUserRoles.RoleId = a.RoleId
    From AspNetUsers as b 
    Inner Join AspNetUserRoles as a
        On a.UserId = b.Id 
    Where b.Email = 'some@email.com'
      and  a.name = 'name'
```